Creating particles from SVG data
I want to convert SVG data to ShapeGeometry, then turn it into particles and display them.
The following code converts multiple SVG data into vertex coordinates.
const getSVGPositions = (svgPath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const loader = new SVGLoader();
    loader.load(
      svgPath,
      (data) => {
        const group = new THREE.Group();
        const paths = data.paths;

        paths.forEach((path) => {
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: path.color,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            depthWrite: false,
          });

          const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes(path);
          shapes.forEach((shape) => {
            const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
            const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            group.add(mesh);
          });
        });

        const particlesPositionsArray = changedParticlePosition(group);
        const flattenedPositions = new Float32Array(
          particlesPositionsArray.reduce(
            (acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.from(val)),
            []
          )
        );
        resolve(flattenedPositions);
      },
      undefined,
      reject
    );
  });
};

const changedParticlePosition = (group) => {
  const numParticles = 10000;
  const particlesPositionsArray = group.children.map((mesh) => {
    const sampler = new MeshSurfaceSampler(mesh).build();
    const particlesPosition = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
    for (let i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {
      const newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
      const normal = new THREE.Vector3();

      sampler.sample(newPosition, normal);
      particlesPosition.set(
        [newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z],
        i * 3
      );
    }
    return particlesPosition;
  });
  return particlesPositionsArray;
};

The following code adds the obtained vertex coordinates to the attributes of BufferGeometry.
Looking at console.log(geometry), we can confirm that the vertex coordinates of position1, position2 ... are stored in an array.
const setGeometryAttributes = (stage, positionsArray) => {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  positionsArray.forEach((positions, index) => {
    geometry.setAttribute(
      `position${index + 1}`,
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3)
    );
  });

  const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: document.querySelector("#js-fragment-shader").textContent,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);

  stage.scene.add(mesh);
};

Below is the vertexShader.
export const vertexShader = /* glsl */ `
attribute vec3 position1;
attribute vec3 position2;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform float u_time;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position1, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 3.0;
}
`;

It's the whole code.
class Stage {
  constructor() {
    this.renderParam = {
      clearColor: 0x000000,
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    };
    this.cameraParam = {
      fov: 45,
      near: 0.1,
      far: 2000,
      lookAt: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      x: 0,
      y: -125,
      z: 1800,
    };

    this.scene = null;
    this.camera = null;
    this.renderer = null;
    this.isInitialized = false;
    this.isDev = false;
  }

  init() {
    this._setScene();
    this._setRender();
    this._setCamera();
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.onResize());
  }

  _setScene() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  }

  _setRender() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(this.renderParam.clearColor));
    this.renderer.setSize(this.renderParam.width, this.renderParam.height);
    const wrapper = document.querySelector("#fv-webgl");
    wrapper.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }

  _setCamera() {
    if (!this.isInitialized) {
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        this.cameraParam.fov,
        this.renderParam.width / this.renderParam.height,
        this.cameraParam.near,
        this.cameraParam.far
      );

      this.camera.position.set(
        this.cameraParam.x,
        this.cameraParam.y,
        this.cameraParam.z
      );
      this.camera.lookAt(this.cameraParam.lookAt);

      this.isInitialized = true;
    }

    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.aspect = windowWidth / windowHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  }

  _render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    if (this.isDev) this.orbitcontrols.update();
  }

  onResize() {
    this.renderParam.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.renderParam.height = window.innerHeight;
    this._setCamera();
  }

  onRaf() {
    this._render();
  }
}

const getSVGPositions = (svgPath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const loader = new SVGLoader();
    loader.load(
      svgPath,
      (data) => {
        const group = new THREE.Group();
        const paths = data.paths;

        paths.forEach((path) => {
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: path.color,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            depthWrite: false,
          });

          const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes(path);
          shapes.forEach((shape) => {
            const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
            const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            group.add(mesh);
          });
        });

        const particlesPositionsArray = changedParticlePosition(group);
        const flattenedPositions = new Float32Array(
          particlesPositionsArray.reduce(
            (acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.from(val)),
            []
          )
        );
        resolve(flattenedPositions);
      },
      undefined,
      reject
    );
  });
};

const setGeometryAttributes = (stage, positionsArray) => {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  positionsArray.forEach((positions, index) => {
    geometry.setAttribute(
      `position${index + 1}`,
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3)
    );
  });

  const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: document.querySelector("#js-fragment-shader").textContent,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);

  stage.scene.add(mesh);
};

const changedParticlePosition = (group) => {
  const numParticles = 10000;
  const particlesPositionsArray = group.children.map((mesh) => {
    const sampler = new MeshSurfaceSampler(mesh).build();
    const particlesPosition = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
    for (let i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {
      const newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
      const normal = new THREE.Vector3();

      sampler.sample(newPosition, normal);
      particlesPosition.set(
        [newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z],
        i * 3
      );
    }
    return particlesPosition;
  });
  return particlesPositionsArray;
};

class Webgl {
  constructor() {
    const stage = new Stage();
    stage.init();
    const svgPaths = ["../images/test.svg", "../images/0.svg"];

    Promise.all(svgPaths.map(getSVGPositions))
      .then((positionsArray) => {
        setGeometryAttributes(stage, positionsArray);
      })
      .catch(console.error);

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      stage.onResize();
    });

    const _raf = () => {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        _raf();

        stage.onRaf();
      });
    };
    _raf();
  }
}

new Webgl();


I want to display the vertex coordinates of the particles added to BufferGeometry.
